How do you improve Interaction to Next Paint (INP) for mobile button click?
I have a static site and my INP for mobile is in the 200-300 range, just insde the "Needs improvement" bucket. I've tried debugging with web-vitals.js to figure out where the latency is coming from. I ended up building a super small proof-of-concept after narrowing down where the interaction was coming from. The following code results in a 248ms delay when I click the button for mobile in Chrome:
<!-- test.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <button>Share</button>
  </body>
</html>

There is no CSS, Javascript, or any other scripts running on the page but I'm still seeing latencies as high as 240ms. I'm using Chrome's Performance tab to measure the result. Any suggestions on improving this?

Do you have a meta viewport set? See: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

@BarryPollard This is strange. I have viewport set as this:

However, when I change this to:

Everything drops back to normal and I start seeing values around 40ms.

As discussed in the comments, if you don't have a meta viewport set (or have one set to zoomed out), then mobile devices assume your site is not responsive, and enable a special "double tap to zoom" mode.
It gives up to 300ms to see if you're going to tap again. This badly affects INP since it's above the 200ms good threshold!
Telling the device you have a responsive, mobile-friendly, website disables this feature and avoids the issue.
See also: developer.chrome.com/blog/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

Testing it locally gives me a low score but when I run a PageSpeed test on web.dev, I still see 300+ms: https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-currenttimeutc-com/9s5yc4d5y6?hl=en&form_factor=mobile

The section at the top of PSI is based on the last 28-day average of real people using your site. It will take typically 304 weeks after deploying it to see the results change there. See here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/04/complete-guide-measure-core-web-vitals/#the-chrome-user-experience-report-crux

Ah gotcha, I figured it was a realtime test. Thanks for the response!

The bottom bit (Diagnose performance issues) is the real time test. The top bit is gathered from real users and that's done over 28 days to get a more accurate picture rather than a highly variable one.
